# Why does boost::process crash on Windows when stderr is redirected to a pipe?

Tags: c++, windows, boost

This code based on `boost::process` 1.65.1 samples with some spelling errors fixed:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::future<std::vector<char>> output, error;
    boost::process::child c("hostname.exe",
        boost::process::std_out > output,
        boost::process::std_err > boost::process::null,
        ios);
    ios.run();
    c.wait();
    if (output.valid())
    {
        auto processOutput = output.get();
        processOutput.push_back('\0');
        printf(processOutput.data());
    }
    if (error.valid())
    {
        auto processError = error.get();
        processError.push_back('\0');
        printf(processError.data());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected. It runs `hostname.exe` and prints its output, i. e. your computer network name.

You probably see that `error` variable is unused. It is logical to read also `stderr`, even `hostname.exe` doesn't use it usually, realistic child process may of course use it. It looks trivial to just replace `boost::process::std_err > boost::process::null` with `boost::process::std_err > error`. However, it results in crash. The error message follows:

```
vector iterator not dereferencable
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to bypass this bug?

Comment: I actually found fix already. The fix needs to edit one of boost hpp files. It is boost bug, I hope they will fix it officially soon.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in Boost Process. The crash appears at `include\boost\process\detail\windows\async_out.hpp` The code that causes crash follows:

```
arg.resize(buffer->size());
is.read(&*arg.begin(), buffer->size());
```

It is not important whether we redirect `std_err` or `std_out`. The problem appears when stream doesn't generate any output. For `hostname.exe` it is `std_err`, however, if you will try to run `pyw.exe`, you'll get this error for `std_out` also.

When progam generates no output, `buffer->size()` returns 0, so the vector becomes an empty one. And it looks like attempt to dereference an empty vector results in crash (debug assertion) at Visual C++.

The fix follows:

```
auto bufferSize = buffer->size();
if (bufferSize) {
    arg.resize(buffer->size());
    is.read(&*arg.begin(), buffer->size());
}
```

I didn't submit this bug report to boost, if anyone has time, lets he does it.

Comment: There's an existing issue for it ([#106](https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process/issues/106)) and it has been fixed in develop.

Comment: Sadly, the fix is not released because the 1.65.1 tag is mistagged to be identical to 1.64.0

Comment: https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process/issues/127 created a new issue about that